# Subplots are getting cut off Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, figure, subplot

I'm having trouble with a plotting program I'm writing. The program basically plots 4 subplots of data of the same size in one figure. A for loops saves about 100 of these figures using plt.subplot(). The issue I am having is that for more than half of the figure the bottom 2 subplots are cut off with a gray band, not just the axis labels, but the figures themselves. I tried adjusting the figsize of the plot but making it larger actually makes the problem worse. Making the figsize smaller actually gets rid of the gray band but hurts the axis labels. I'm posting my code below. I'm using a much older version of matplotlib (1.5.1) so maybe that's the issue, but to be honest I have never seen this before. It's almost like the last bit of the figure is not saving.

My code to generate the figures is posted below, any help would be greatly appreciated. I wish I could post a figure but I do not have enough stack overflow points =P

```
crop = np.s_[inds_up[lbl]:inds_down[lbl], inds_left[lbl]:inds_right[lbl]]
saveloc = generate_saveloc(inds_up[lbl],inds_down[lbl], inds_left[lbl],inds_right[lbl], granule.save_folder)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
fig.suptitle("Diagnostic at Crop %d : %d, %d : %d" % (inds_up[lbl],inds_down[lbl], inds_left[lbl],inds_right[lbl]))

vmin = 271.15 if np.nanmin(layers['sst'][crop][layers['spt'][crop]!=3]) < 271.15 else np.nanmin(layers['sst'][crop][layers['spt'][crop]!=3])
vmax = np.nanmax(layers['sst'][crop][layers['spt'][crop]!=3])

ax1 = plt.subplot(221)
ax1.set_title("Sea Surface Temperature", fontsize=10)
ax1.axis('off')
img1 = ax1.imshow(layers['sst'][crop],vmin=vmin,vmax=vmax)
div1 = make_axes_locatable(ax1)
cax1 = div1.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
cbar1 = plt.colorbar(img1, cax=cax1)

ax2 = plt.subplot(222)
ax2.set_title('Albedo', fontsize=10)
ax2.axis('off')
img1 = ax2.imshow(layers['albedo'][crop], vmin=0, vmax=10, cmap='gray')
div1 = make_axes_locatable(ax2)
cax1 = div1.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
cbar1 = plt.colorbar(img1, cax=cax1)

ax2 = plt.subplot(223)
ax2.set_title('SST Gradient Magnitude', fontsize=10)
ax2.axis('off')
img1 = ax2.imshow(layers['gradient'][crop],vmin=0, vmax=0.5, cmap='gray')
div1 = make_axes_locatable(ax2)
cax1 = div1.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
cbar1 = plt.colorbar(img1, cax=cax1)


ticklabels = ['Agreed Clear' ,'SPT Cloud','Clear Front','SPT Clear', 'Agreed Cloud','Cloud Front']
ax2 = plt.subplot(224)
ax2.set_title('Questionable', fontsize=10)
ax2.axis('off')
img1 = ax2.imshow(layers['overlay'][crop],cmap=cmap_overlay,vmin=-0.5,vmax=5.5)
div1 = make_axes_locatable(ax2)
cax1 = div1.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
cbar1 = plt.colorbar(img1, cax=cax1,ticks=np.linspace(0,5,6))
cbar1.set_ticklabels(ticklabels)

#plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig(saveloc, bbox_layout='tight')
plt.savefig(saveloc)
plt.close()
```

Update:
Turns out the issue is not related to matplotlib or savefig. I am using sshfs to view the files from a separate server on my computer. When I view them with eog the gray band shows up but when I uploaded the figures to google drive the gray band wasn't present. This suggests the problem lies in my connection with server. Thank you for your responses.

Comment: You're saving the plot twice, and you've commented out `tight_layout()`. Any reason for that?

Comment: If you post a link to an image on imgur someone might edit it into your question for you :) also, is it possible to make this into a [MCVE]?

Comment: I think you should be able to add an image, even if not having enough points. The only difference will be that the image is shown as a link in the post instead of being displayed directly. Showing that image seems to be crucial for understanding the issue, so you may spend some time on getting it here.